# Pascal - split string to array by each character

Tags: string, pascal

I'm trying to find solution, how can I split string like this:

```
abkgwvc
```

to `array` by character? Expected output is:

```
array[0] = a
array[3] = g
...
```

any idea?

---

**Solution**:

```
for i := 0 to length(string) do
begin
    array[i] = copy(string, i, 1);
end;
```

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: this page might help you http://math.uww.edu/~harrisb/courses/cs171/strings.html

Comment: maybe I can use copy? See my edited question

Comment: Your solution is mostly correct, except that your destination array is 0-based and the 3rd parameter to `Copy` is the number of characters to copy, not the final index.

Comment: Strings use a 1-based index in Turbo Pascal. Assuming your array is zero-based, you can actually just do `array[i] = string[i+1];` in your loop body and then correct the `for` to go only up to `length(string)-1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A string can be accessed as an array of characters directly, so there's no need to use `Copy`. The example below is based on versions of Delphi/Lazarus that support dynamic arrays, but you can use an old-style fixed length array (`Arr: array[..] of Char`) the same way; just remove the `SetLength` call and change the declaration to the right array type.

```
var
  Str: string;
  Arr: array of Char;
  i: Integer;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Str := 'abkgwvc';
  Len := Length(Str);
  SetLength(arr, Len);

  // Dynamic arrays are 0-based indexing, while
  // strings are 1 based. We need to subtract 1
  // from the array index.
  for i := 1 to Len do
    Arr[i - 1] := Str[i];  
end;
```

(Of course, if you're *not* using dynamic arrays, it's not clear why you'd need a separate array in the first place; you can just access the string char-by-char directly.)

Comment: In TP he is most likely to use shortstrings, which are the default "string" there. No setlength, length assignment is s[0]:=chr(len);

Comment: @Marco: The `SetLength` is being used on a dynamic array, not a string, and I covered older fixed length arrays in the first paragraph. :) Setting the zero byte to a value doesn't set an array's size, only that of a shortstring. `Length(s)` applies to both `ShortString` and modern strings.